# Mysql table populated with binary table values

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an easy way to generate a mysql table which is a binary table of a specified number of binary bits? Each row should have an Id column where the value equals the decimal value of the binary number, i.e.: 0,1,2,3,4,5....

for example say I specified 3 bits, the generated mysql table would look like this:

0    0 0 0

1    0 0 1

2    0 1 0

3    0 1 1

4    1 0 0

5    1 0 1

6   1 1 0

7    1 1 1

I would like to be able to just specify the number of binary bits and have it create a table and populate it appropriately depending on the number of bit required. Any ideas? I am wondering if there is a standard Sql function for this?

Comment: What are the columns in the table?

Comment: it is just a binary table so they would be 2^n, 2^n-1, 2^n-2 .... 2^0. I have been able to do this in excel with a macro but it is slow to run for larger tables. I am wondering if there is a quicker and easier implementation with Mysql and sql?

Comment: There is not a quicker and easier implementation in MySQL, unless you are already starting with some sort of numbers or tally table.

Comment: use conv( ) to generate binary from decimal : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-conv-function.php